# group different periods with a new variable

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I have da dataset which has one column with several observations across one year. I want to analyse short term and long term changes in a later stage. To do so I need to defined a new variable `time` which shows if the date of my observation is between different dates.
Reproducable Dataframe:

```
Dataset <- data.frame = category=c("tools", "finance", "business", "education","tools","education"), 
date=c("2017-05-12","2018-06-07","2018-03-28","2018-05-18","2018-07-22","2018-06-03")
number_trackers = c(10, 12, 1, 30, 7, 21), 
c4 = c("url1.com","ur2.com","url3.com","url4.com","url5.com","url6.com"),
time=c( ,  ,  ,  ,  , )
```

I have different columns but just the new variable `time` and `date` is important for this problem.
I tried to do it in the following code but I got an error.

```
  if ( between(DatasetApp$analysis_date, "2018-06-28", "2018-10-28")) {
    DatasetApp$time="short-term"
  } else if (between (DatasetApp$analysis_date,  "2018-06-28", "2018-12-28")) {
    DatasetApp$time="long-term"
  } else if ( between (DatasetApp$analysis_date,  "2017-05-28", "2018-04-28")) {
    DatasetApp$time="before"
  }
```

Comment: Can you share sample data using `dput` function?

Comment: the ```dput``` ouput looks a bit messy because I have a lot variables/columns in my dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `cut` function. You can do something like :-

```
Dataset <- data.frame(
    category=c("tools", "finance", "business", "education","tools","education"), 
    date= as.Date(c("2017-05-12","2018-06-07","2018-03-28","2018-05-18","2018-07-22","2018-06-03")),
    number_trackers = c(10, 12, 1, 30, 7, 21), 
    c4 = c("url1.com","ur2.com","url3.com","url4.com","url5.com","url6.com"))

Dataset$time <- cut(Dataset$date, 
                    breaks = as.Date(c("2017-05-28", "2018-06-28", "2018-10-28", "2018-12-28")),
                    labels = c("before", "short-term", "long-term"))
```

By the way I am not sure if the this intentional, the date ranges you specified in your example don't seem reasonable. There is an overlap between your short-term and long-term date ranges.

If you want the ranges to overlap, then you'd have to decide the priority of different ranges. For instance, in your example, the date `2018-07-22` falls in both `short-term` and `long-term` ranges.

Assuming that the priority order is `short-term > long-term > before` you can do the following :-

```
Dataset$time <- NA

Dataset[Dataset$date >= "2018-06-28" & 
            Dataset$date < "2018-10-28" & 
            is.na(Dataset$time), "time"] <- "short-term"
Dataset[Dataset$date >= "2018-06-28" & 
            Dataset$date < "2018-12-28" & 
            is.na(Dataset$time), "time"] <- "long-term"
Dataset[Dataset$date >= "2017-05-28" & 
            Dataset$date < "2018-04-28"& 
            is.na(Dataset$time), "time"] <- "before"
```

The above code will assign `long-term` to a row iff it falls within the specified date range and does not fall in the range of `short-term`. Similarly, `before` will be assigned iff it falls in the specified date range and does not fall within the ranges of `short-term` or `long-term`.

Comment: Do you have an Idea how I can work with these overlaps? In the later process, I have to compare the three periods with each other.

Comment: I have edited the answer to account for overlaps